# Why define types in RHS rather than LHS?

Tags: scala

Recently I came across some code that defines types as follows:

```
val a = "Hello":String
```

rather than:

```
val a:String = "Hello"
```

Is there any advantage of the first notation? Maybe, perhaps in compilation?

Comment: The first one relies on type inference to determine the type of `a`. As Alexey Romanov says below, this isn't allowed for recursive definitions, but it can also get you into trouble with implicit defs (see [this simple example](https://gist.github.com/travisbrown/1f443b5358231f0e75bf)).

Comment: Didn't think of that. For more fun, it depends on order: if you define `object Foo` before `Bar`, it [does compile](http://scastie.org/12593).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One marginal benefit I can think of is that the first notation can be used *inside* an expression, e.g. `(a: String) + b`, if you don't want to give the complete type or want to trigger an implicit conversion (of course, you can do both while still giving the type on the left as well). On the other hand, the second one:

1. is required for recursive values and methods, as well as abstract members;
2. is more widely used;
3. doesn't require parentheses around the expression in cases like `(a + b): String`;
4. allows you to see the signature more immediately if the definition takes more than one line.

I can't think of any other significant differences.

Answer (score 0):

This is type ascription. It's basically a compile-time cast in scala. I don't feel like

```
val a = "Hello": String
```

is a proper use, it should be exactly the same as `val a: String = "Hello"` but it reads harder. You can check it in REPL: `val b: String = 5` and `val b = 5:String` both generate compile-time error, when `val b = 5.asInstanceOf[String]` generates runtime error

However type ascription has a few very nice usages. `a:_*` is probably the most popular. You also able to trigger implicit conversions with it:

```
implicit def aToB(i: A): B = A.makeB()

(new A()) : B // will run A.makeB()
```

Comment: This answer isn't necessarily _wrong_, but it's potentially confusing in at least a couple of ways. When most people hear "casting" they're likely to think of downcasting, which is unsafe and can result in runtime errors. Type ascriptions are technically "casting" (in the sense that they provide support for _upcasting_), but they are always type-safe. Also `_*` is special syntax for sequence arguments.